# nested array element count based on index

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm, odm

my documents are like this

```
{"_id":"5de7fdb37d444b7a49236c83","list_id":[[3,2,4]]}
{"_id":"5de7fdb37d444b7a49236c83","list_id":[[2,4]]}
{"_id":"5de7fdb37d444b7a49236c83","list_id":[[3,2]]}
```

how can i count based on list id elemnts 3 , 2 ,4.

they are nested array element..

i tried

```
$usersQuery = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder(ClientUser::class)
        ->field('list_id.0.0')
        ->equals([2])
        ->getQuery();
        $usersCount = $usersQuery->count();
```

for 1st elemnt usercount is 1 which is fine ,
but for other element like 2 and 4 , query doesnt work .
like i tried

```
 $usersQuery = $this->dm->createQueryBuildebut r(ClientUser::class)
        ->field('list_id.0.1')
        ->equals(3)->count(); (edited) 
or
  $usersQuery = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder(ClientUser::class)
        ->field('list_id.0.1')
        ->equals([3])
        ->getQuery()->count();
```

it is not working for consecutive array element
please suggest

Comment: what do you mean - "how can i count based on elemnt 3 , 2 ,4."?

Comment: edited my question .. elaborated more